# Programatically testing an image as wallpaper

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have to display an image in the home screen with all apps icons programatically within the application for testing whether the image suits for the screen.Any ideas? Would be much appreciated!!

Comment: what idea you have?!!!!

Comment: @mvp Is it possible to take a screen shot of app icons in a transparent page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry but iOS does not let you set a wallpaper programmatically or provide any way of knowing what is in the user's home screen.

The only solution I can think for your problem would be to create a simulated home screen yourself so you can show how the wallpapers look with the icons on top.

Maybe have a app icon library and let the user choose which app icons to simulate on the home screen. Although this would require a lot of maintenance to keep the icons up to date and it will probably be more trouble than its worth.